# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error when calling ajax call localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, cors

I'm trying to send a request via GET method and get JSON response from the server hosted in the following URL. I need to send get a request like this.

```
http://localhost:9763/services/PMT_Dashboard/getid/222
```

I wrote an HTML page and include it javascript file contains the ajax call. The code is followed.

```
function loadDoc(){
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:9763/services/PMT_Dashboard/getid/222',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "Application/json")
        }, success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
})}
```

But in console, it says following error,

> index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9763/services/PMT_Dashboard/getid/222. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

please help me where I'm wrong and give me a solution to fix this issue. **I want to run server and client in locally.**

Comment: Rather odd you're getting a pre-flight request if the domains are the same. The only things I can suggest is to change `url` to a relative path, and change `beforeSend` to `contentType: 'json'`

Comment: *Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.* sounds like the problem is the  document the request is being made from is loaded from a file: URL rather than from `http://localhost:9763` (or from any other web server)

Answer (score 0):

Put following snippet in your API's code(**localhost:9763/services/PMT_Dashboard/getid/222**),  if implemented in JS.

```
if (request.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    response = response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT');
  }
```